# Calling passport.authenticate in a separate function isn't working

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm relatively new to Node and Passport and I was experimenting with login forms using OAuth. I had no problems with setting up Passport and it was completely functional.

It only broke down when I started cleaning up the code to separate the routes from the middlewares.

I've included a part of my code before and after the changes.

So, this works:

```js
module.exports = function(app, passport) {
   app.get('/login', loginIndex)
    
 app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect : '/profile',
        failureRedirect : '/login',
        failureFlash : true
    }))
    
    function loginIndex(req, res) {
   res.render('login.ejs', {message: req.flash('loginMessage')})
    }
}
```

But this does not:

```js
module.exports = function(app, passport) {
  app.get('/login', loginIndex)
  app.post('/login', loginAuth)

  function loginIndex(req, res) {
   res.render('login.ejs', {message: req.flash('loginMessage')});
  }


  function loginAuth(){
     passport.authenticate('local-login', {
          successRedirect : '/profile',
          failureRedirect : '/login',
          failureFlash : true
      }) 
  }
}
```

So, the only difference between the two is that I've moved the passport.authenticate() call into the function loginAuth().
I guess it has to do with the internal working of passport.authenticate(), but I'm not sure.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at Stormpath? Disclaimer: I work there. We are a secure, hosted user management solution.  Our [express-stormpath](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-express) module makes it very easy to add login pages to your Express application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 app.post('/login', loginAuth())
```

...

```
function loginAuth(){
      return passport.authenticate('local-login', {
          successRedirect : '/profile',
          failureRedirect : '/login',
          failureFlash : true
      })    
  }
```

In your original code, you are executing `passport.authenticate` and in the second version you are just passing a function without executing the passport logic.